# removing Ubuntu 14

Tags: boot, removing

I have installed BY ITSELF Ubuntu into a computer (replacing Windows 8 altogether). There is no other operating system in this computer. Now I want to remove it and reinstall windows 8 and I have no idea how to do it. this is NOT a dual boot system. For the time being Ubuntu is the only operating system in it. Everything I have read so far points to removing from a "Dual Boot" system.This is not a dual boot system I have. It only contains Ubuntu, which I would like to remove.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot into ubuntu live disc
2. Open gparted and delete all the partitions on your hard drive
3. Boot into a windows live disc
4. Follow the steps and install windows (you will see unallocated space from which you can create drives)
5. You now have a fresh windows install with no ubuntu

If you cannot understand any step please let me know and I will try my best to clarify further

Comment: Okay, lets just say that I cannot get my computer to boot from any thing but Ubuntu. In windows it's easy to change the boot sequence so it will but from cd/usb, but in Ubuntu I have no idea how to make it happen. I have tried so many reboot/restore programs in various formats but I still Cannot Get this computer to boot from anything but the primary system.
I need to know how to get it to boot from a usb or a cd. How cryptic is it to do such a thing?

Comment: when you start you computer, go into the boot menu (see this chart for the button to press https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive). you have to press the button right after the computer turns on. then you can select which device you wish to boot into.